# why all the exception classes need to be serializable

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why should I always make my Exceptions [serializable]? (.NET)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066701/why-should-i-always-make-my-exceptions-serializable-net)

Any one know the reason for that?

Comment: Same as [Why should I always make my Exceptions serializable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066701/why-should-i-always-make-my-exceptions-serializable-net).

Comment: Well, they don't need to be serializable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because exceptions can be transmitted across process boundaries, or even machine boundaries (e.g. when using remoting). Being serializable helps a lot in those cases.