# Should I make my CustomException serializable?

Tags: c#, exception, serializable

I'm defining a custom exception class to signal to my handler for a specific action to be taken. I'm wondering if I should make my exception Serializable or not. I don't intend to use the exception as anything more than an exit from my current execution.

(and yes, I do need a custom exception class. I'm pretty sure about that)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why should I always make my Exceptions \[serializable\]? (.NET)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066701/why-should-i-always-make-my-exceptions-serializable-net)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best practice is to make them serializable. This way they can be serialized across AppDomain, or even process, boundaries.

Comment: Microsoft guidelines on Custom Exception: [Designing Custom Exceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229064.aspx)

Comment: That comment contains a dead link now :-(

Comment: Updated link (just changed the .net version to 4) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229064(v=vs.100).aspx